# What is the correct Power Steering Fluid for a 2001 Jeep Cherokee XJ?

Tags: jeep, cherokee, power-steering-fluid

What is the correct Power Steering Fluid for a 2001 Jeep Cherokee XJ?

I called a Jeep Chrysler dealership, and they said to not to use an ATF +4.

Then I went to another Jeep Chrysler dealership, and they said the proper fluid is MOPAR ATF +4.  So I bought a quart.  The numbers on it are MS-9602 and 68218057AB.

Do I have the correct power steering fluid?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this website](https://www.morris4x4center.com/knowledge-base/jeep-cherokee-xj-fluid-capacities-type?find=jeep-cherokee-xj-2001-129052) you can use:

> Power Steering Fluid +4 (If unavailable ATF+4 is Acceptable)

Searching through things, it's the Grand Cherokee which requires the different power steering fluid and cannot use the ATF+4. This is due to it being an electric pump and supplying pressure to the cooling fan (or some such). The fluid used in the GC has friction modifiers.

Comment: I wish that site included a reference for their claim.  I've now called 5 Jeep dealerships and 2 said definitely *not* to use ATF +4 fluid, 2 said it was fine, and 1 didn't know.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - There are too many people out there who hear "Cherokee" and confuse with "Grand Cherokee" (even the dealership stooges). I've given you the reason *why* you shouldn't use the ATF +4 in the Grand Cherokee (because it has the electric pump and use through cooling fan). I don't blame your trepidation, though. I would want it to be right for my vehicle, too.

Answer (score -1):

Fact, For jeeps 2001-2004 with hydraulic fans only use Valvoline power steering fluid Chrysler Spec: 5931/part number 799222

Comment: Because of German technology the 2001-2004 jeep grand cherokee have hydraulic fans that require specific ATF+4 for the transmission.  The power steering fluid required is Valvoline Chrysler Spec: 5931/part number 799222

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).